# AH01630: client denied by server configuration issue

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2

After I changed something in my file(s) in my Linux server, my whole layout in website collapsed. This is how it looks

[myawsdjapp.com](https://myawsdjapp.com)

And below is the error log.

```
[Mon Feb 17 12:52:23.636400 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 7845:tid 140639593273088] [client 121.131.97.11:49904] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/djtu/django_project/staticblog, referer: https://www.myawsdjapp.com/
```

Weird thing is, I don't have folder named 'staticblog'. Here's my ls command result.

```
$ ls -la /home/djtu/django_project/
total 228
drwxrwxr-x 8 djtu www-data   4096 Feb 16 19:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 17 12:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu       6148 Feb 15 14:56 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 6 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 14:56 blog
-rw-rw-r-- 1 djtu www-data 167936 Feb 16 19:58 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 3 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 17 11:59 django_project
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu        634 Feb 15 14:56 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 djtu www-data   4096 Feb 15 14:56 media
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu      13994 Feb 15 14:56 posts.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 djtu djtu        624 Feb 15 14:56 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 16 20:22 static
drwxr-xr-x 5 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 16 18:55 users
drwxrwxr-x 5 djtu djtu       4096 Feb 15 16:58 venv
```

And this is my virtual host setting file. I used certbot.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static/ /home/djtu/django_project/static
        <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static/ /home/djtu/django_project/media
        <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/django_project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/djtu/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess dj_app python-path=/home/djtu/django_project python-home=/home/djtu/django_project/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup dj_app

ServerName www.myawsdjapp.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myawsdjapp.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.myawsdjapp.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I used Django 3.0.2 and Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu 19.10). Can someone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

### EDIT

Ok I see some typo. I should have typed media instead of static.

```
    Alias /media/ /home/djtu/django_project/media
    <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Now I see some more error logs unfortunately.

```
[Mon Feb 17 13:17:56.045119 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 8038:tid 139797571966720] [client 121.131.97.11:49951] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/djtu/django_project/mediadefault.jpg, referer: https://www.myawsdjapp.com/
[Mon Feb 17 13:17:56.045524 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 8038:tid 139797486102272] [client 121.131.97.11:49950] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/djtu/django_project/staticblog, referer: https://www.myawsdjapp.com/
[Mon Feb 17 13:17:56.118468 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 8038:tid 139797580359424] [client 121.131.97.11:49951] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/djtu/django_project/mediaprofile_pics, referer: https://www.myawsdjapp.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. I should have put '/' at the end of Alias. It made all the differences.

```
        Alias /static/ /home/djtu/django_project/static/
        <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media/ /home/djtu/django_project/media/
        <Directory /home/djtu/django_project/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I invested a lot of time and read many threads about this issue. At the end I could fix that error by adding following into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /opt/myproject>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I had the same in my .conf but this one did it for me.